# Is the "Challenge Accepted" achievement broken?

Tags: achievements, borderlands-2

I'm having trouble getting the "Challenge Accepted" achievement (on Xbox, but this might be on other platforms too)

The text reads:

> **Challenge Accepted**
>
> Completed level 1 of all non-level-specific challenges with a single character

I've done that - every non-level-specific challenge shows at level 2 or higher (most are maxed out) but I still don't have the achievement.

1. Am I missing something?
2. Is this achievement glitched in some way?
3. If (2) then is there any way to fix it?

Comment: I can confirm that it isn't glitched on PC. It just takes some time to unlock, it seems.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

There are some challenges that don't appear until you've completed others:

**Enemies:**

- Little Person, Big Pain: Kill 10 Midgets
- Load and Lock: Kill 20 Loaders
- Bully the Bullies: Kill 25 Bullymongs
- Cruising for a Bruising: Kill 10 Bruisers
- Marauder? I Hardly Know 'Er: Kill 20 Marauders
- You Dirty Rat: Kill 10 Rats
- Mama's Boys: Kill 50 Psychos
- You (No)Mad, Bro?: Kill 10 Nomads
- Short-Chained: Shoot a chain to release midgets from shield
- Hurly Burly: Shoot 10 bullymong-tossed projectiles out of midair
- Just a Moment of Your Time...: Kill 10 surveyors
- WHY SO MICH HIRT?!: Kill 10 goliaths
- Paigineering: Kill 10 Hyperion personnel
- Constructor Destructor: Kill 5 constructors
- Another Bug Hunt: Kill 10 varkids *(Unlocked with Tundra Express)*
- Tentacle Obsession: Kill 10 threshers *(Unlocked with Highlands - Outwash)*
- Pest Control: Kill 10 spiderants *(Unlocked with Frostburn Canyon)*
- Crystals Are a Girl's Best Friend: Kill 10 crystalisks *(Unlocked with The Fridge)*
- Pod Pew Pew: Kill 10 Varkid pods before they hatch *(Unlocked with Tundra Express)*
- Die in the Friendly Skies: Kill 10 buzzards *(Unlocked with The Dust)*
- You're One Ugly Mother...: Kill 10 stalkers *(Unlocked with The Highlands - Outwash)
- Skags to Riches: Kill 10 skags *(Unlocked with Three Horns - Divide)*

**Elemental:**

- Slag-Licked: Deal 5000 bonus damage to Slagged enemies
- Boom.: Kill 20 enemies with explosive damage
- Cowering Inferno: Ignite 25 enemies
- Say 'Watt' Again: Deal 5000 electrocute damage
- Corroderate: Deal 2500 corrosion damage
- I Just Want to Set the World on Fire: Deal 5000 burn damage
- Acid Trip: Kill 20 enemies with corrode damage

**Loot**

- Open Pandora's Boxes: Open 50 lootable chests, lockers, and other objects
- The Call of Booty: Open 5 treasure chests
- Nothing Rymes with Orange: Loot or purchase 1 orange item
- Purple Reign: Loot or purchase 2 purple items
- I Like My Treasure Rare: Loot or purchase 5 blue items
- It's Not Easy Looting Green: Loot or purchase 20 green items
- Another Man's Treasure: Loot or purchase 50 white items
- Gun Runner: Pick up or purchase 10 weapons

**Money & Trading:**

- Psst, Hey Buddy...: Trade with 1 other player
- Whaddaya Buyin'?: Purchase 2 items with Eridium
- Limited-Time Offer: Buy 1 "Item of the Day"
- Wholesale: Sell 10 items to vending machines
- For the Hoard!: Save $10,000
- Dolla Dolla Bills, Y'all: Pickup $5,000 from cash drops

**Vehicle:**

- Passive Aggressive: Kill 1 enemy while riding as a passenger
- Turret Syndrome: Kill 10 enemies with a turret or vehicle mounted weapon
- Blue Sparks: Kill 5 enemies while power sliding
- Hit-and-Fun: Kill 5 enemies by ramming them with a vehicle
- ...One Van Leaves - Kill 5 vehicles while in a vehicle

**Health & Recovery:**

- I'll Just Help Myself: Get 5 "Second Winds" by killing an enemy
- This Is No Time for Lazy!: Revive a co-op partner 5 times
- Badass Bingo: Get 1 "Second Wind" by killing a badass enemy
- Heal Plz: Heal 1000 points worth of damage
- Death, Wind, and Fire: Get 1 "Second Wind" by killing an enemy with burn damage over time *(Unlocked after Cowering Inferno level 1)*
- Green Meanie: Get 1 "Second Wind" by killing an enemy with corrosive damage over time *(Unlocked after completing Acid Trip level 1)*
- I'm Back! Shocked?: Get 1 "Second Wind" by killing an enemy by electrocution damage over time *(Unlocked after Say "Watt" Again level 1)*

**Grenades:**

- Woah, Black Betty: Kill 10 enemies with Bouncing Betty grenades
- Health Vampire: Kill 10 enemies with Transfusion grenades
- Pull the Pin: Kill 10 enemies with grenades
- Chemical Sprayer: Kill 10 enemies with "Area of Effect" grenades
- EXPLOOOOOSIONS!: Kill 10 enemies with Mirv grenades
- Singled Out: Kill 10 enemies with Singularity grenades

**Shields:**

- Ammo Eater: Absorb 20 ammo with an Absorption shield
- Roid Rage: Kill 5 enemies while buffed by a "Maylay" shield
- Game of Thorns: Kill 5 enemies with reflected damage from a Spike shield
- Amp It Up: Kill 5 enemies while buffed by an Amplify shield
- Super Novas: Kill 5 enemies with a Nova burst shield

**Rocket Launcher:**

- Rocket and Roll: Kill 10 enemies with rocket launchers
- Gone with the Second Wind: Get 2 "Second Winds" with rocket launchers
- Sky Rockets in Flight...: Kill 25 enemies from long range with rocket launchers *(Unlocked after Gone With The Second Wind Level 1)*
- Shield Basher: Kill 5 shielded enemies with 1 rocket each *(Unlocked after Splish Splash level 1)
- Splish Splash - Kill 200 enemies with rocket launcher splash damage *(Unlocked after Rocket And Roll level 1)*
- Catch-a-Rocket: Kill 5 enemies with direct rocket hits *(Unlocked after splish Splash level 5)*

**Sniper Rifle**

- Longshot: Kill 20 enemies with sniper rifles
- Longshot Headshot: Get 25 critical hits with sniper rifles
- Leaf on the Second Wind: Get 2 "Second Winds" using sniper rifles
- Eviscerated: Kill 5 shielded enemies with 1 sniper rifle shot *(Unlocked after Longshot level 1)*
- No Scope, No Problem: Kill 5 enemies without using zoom *(Unlocked after Longshot level 1)*
- Snipe Hunting - Kill 10 enemies with critical hits using sniper rifles *(Unlocked after Longshot Headshot level 1)*
- Surprise! - Kill 5 unaware enemies with sniper rifles *(Unlocked after No Scope, No Problem level 1)*

**Assault Rifle:**

- Aggravated Assault: Kill 25 enemies with assault rifles
- From My Cold, Dead Hands: Get 5 "Second Winds" using assault rifles
- This is My Rifle...: Get 25 critical hits with assault rifles
- ...This is My Gun: Kill 10 enemies with critical hits using assault rifles *(Unlocked after This Is My Rifle... level 1)*
- Crouching Tiger, Hidden Assault Rifle: Kill 25 enemies with assault rifles while crouched *(Unlocked after Aggravated Assault level 1)*

**SMG:**

- Hail of Bullets: Kill 25 enemies with SMGs
- Constructive Criticism: Get 25 critical hits with SMGs
- High Rate of Ire: Kill 10 enemies with critical hits using SMGs
- More Like Submachine FUN: Get 2 "Second Winds" with SMGs *(Unlocked after Constructive Criticism level 1)*

**Shotgun:**

- Faceful of Buckshot: Get 50 critical hits with shotguns
- Shotgun!: Kill 25 enemies with shotguns
- Lock, Stock, and ...: Get 2 "Second Winds" with shotguns
- Shotgun Surgeon: Kill 10 enemies with critical hits using shotguns
- Open Wide!: Kill 750 enemies from point-blank range with shotguns
- Shotgun Sniper: Kill 10 enemies from long range with shotguns *(Unlocked after open Wide! level 5)*

**Pistol:**

- Hard Boiled: Get 2 "Second Winds" with pistols
- The Killer: Kill 25 enemies with pistols
- Deadeye: Get 25 critical hits with pistols
- Quickdraw: Kill 10 enemies shortly after entering ironsights *(Unlocked after The Killer level 1)*
- Pistolero: Kill 10 enemies with critical hits using pistols *(Unlocked after Deadeye level 1)*

**Melee:**

- Fisticuffs!: Kill 25 enemies with melee attacks
- A Squall of Violence: Kill 20 enemies with bladed guns *(Unlocked after Fisticuffs! level 1)*

**General Combat:**

- Knee-Deep in Brass: Fire 1000 rounds
- Afternoon Delight: Kill 50 enemies during the day
- ...To Pay the Bills: Kill 20 enemies while using your action skills
- Critical Acclaim: Kill 20 enemies with critical hits
- ...I got to Boogie: Kill 10 enemies at night
- Boomerbang: Kill 5 enemies with Tediore reloads
- Gun Slinger: Deal 5,000 damage with Tediore reloads
- Not Full of Monkeys: Kill 10 enemies with stationary barrels

**Miscellaneous:**

- JEEEEENKINSSSSSS!!!: Kill Jimmy Jenkins once
- Sidejacked: Complete 5 side missions
- Compl33tionist: Complete 10 optional mission objectives
- Haters Gonna Hate: Win 1 duel
- Yo Dawg I Herd You Like Challenges: Complete 5 challenges

In particular "Shotgun Sniper" and "Catch-a-Rocket" only unlock after completing other challenges to level 5.

Comment: Keith, one thing to note about these hidden challenges. They are *retroactive*, meaning if you've fulfilled the requirements for them, before they are unlocked, you will get the credit for them instantly once they are unlocked!

Comment: @JamesJiao that's good to know, getting 500 point-blank shotgun kills is proving tedious.

Comment: Get a shotgun with a large spread (x12 or more), go to a low level area and spread in their faces.

Comment: @JamesJiao - Yeah, that's just what I'm doing, but running up to level 30 enemies with a level 50 Conference Call 500 times is dull. Still, better than collecting the stupid oil cans/pizza/fish from BL1.

Answer (score 8):

Some may think that the achievement is glitched, but in fact some challenges are unlocked through progress of other challenges, for example:

"Get 200 kills will rocket launcher splash damage" challenge will unlock the "Get 10 direct rocket kills" challenge.

The full list is available at [Challenge Accepted Guide](http://www.xbox360achievements.org/forum/showthread.php?t=384218).

Comment: People think it's glitched because these hidden challenges didn't actually show up in the list *at all*. Since a recent update they show up (on PC, anyway) as Undiscovered.